# RedirectMatch 301 (from example.com/f13/title/ to /forum/f13/title/)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have tried the following statement to redirect www.example.com/f13/title/ to www.example.com/forum/f13/title/ with no luck:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/f(.*)/(.*)/$ http://www.example.com/forum/f$1/$2/
```

I keep getting something like this:

```
www.example.come/forum/forum/forum/forum..../ftopic/title/
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that "`f(.*)`" also matches `/forum/` so you're creating a redirect loop. You can include a negative match to prevent that:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?!forum/)f(.*)/(.*)/$ http://www.example.com/forum/f$1/$2
```